# Smarty variable inside Jquery code issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smarty

When I put SMARTY variable between `{literal}{$txt_more}{/literal}` in Jquery then in source code it display right text (více without quotes) but in console it show this error: 
ReferenceError: v\u00EDce is not defined - this error I thought is because it is not in quotes 
but when I put it into quotes `{literal}'{$txt_more}'{/literal}` it show in source code as 'více' but not display as text between tags strong with class show_text (tags are empty inside). Can you help me ? Thank you very much.

Jquery with SMARTY:

```
$('.show_text').text({/literal}'{$txt_more}'{literal}); // verison with quotes is without error but still not display text between tags with class show_text

$('.show_text').text('show more'); // with show more typed it displays as it should on website
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#">
  <strong class="show_text" style=" margin-top: 5px; text-align:center; overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;position:absolute; z-index:2"></strong>
  <img style="position:relative;" class="cond-arr" src="/css/showmore.png" alt="show_more" />
</a>
```

Comment: What about: `$('.show_text').text("{literal}{$txt_more}{/literal}");` ???

Answer (score 1):

Wrong quoting, should be:

```
$('.show_text').text("{/literal}{$txt_more}{literal}");
```

Comment: That would produce the opposite of the intended result

Comment: @Borgtex i don't know at all smarty, could you elaborate about 'opposite' result? EDIT: ok, was thinking it was a typo in OP's code, my bad

Comment: @Alex Thank you! And indeed, was my first answer before switching it. PS: that's really strange notation imho

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Smarty 3, you don't need {literal} anymore, just make sure that there is always a space after any { in your code

If using smarty 2, you don't need to be so specific with literal, remember that the problem is only when there is a "{". Your code will look much cleaner with one of this solutions:

```
{/literal}
$('.show_text').text('{$txt_more}');
{literal}
```

or using a javascript variable at the start of your code and surrounding everything else with literal just to be safe

```
txt_more='{$txt_more}';

{literal}
...
$('.show_text').text(txt_more);
...
{/literal}
```